# Erro type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<void>

Tags: flutter, dart, tdd

Pessoal eu estou com o seguinte teste:

[image: Erro]

```
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class RemoteAuthentication {
final HttpClient httpClient;
final String url;

RemoteAuthentication({required this.httpClient, required 
this.url});

Future<void> auth() async {
await httpClient.request(url: url);
}
}

abstract class HttpClient {
Future<void> request({required String url});
}

class HttpClientSpy extends Mock implements HttpClient {}

void main() {

test("Deve retornar os dados http com a url correta", () async {
final httpClient = HttpClientSpy();
final url = faker.internet.httpUrl();
final sut = RemoteAuthentication(httpClient: httpClient, url: 
url);
await sut.auth();
verify(httpClient.request(url: url));
});
}
```

e ele esta me retornando o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro]

Algum enviado de deus poderia me dizer o porque desse erro?

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Comment: obrigado pela dica amigo, ja foi adicionado.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After many attempts, this is the only way I could get the code to work. As far as I could find the problem is related with how the mock library deals with methods.

```
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:faker/faker.dart';

class RemoteAuthentication {
  final HttpClient httpClient;
  final String url;

  RemoteAuthentication({required this.httpClient, required this.url});

  Future<void> auth() async {
    await httpClient.request(url: url);
  }
}

abstract class HttpClient {
  Future<void>? request({required String url});
}

class HttpClientSpy extends Mock implements HttpClient {}

void main() {
  test('Should call HttpClient with correct URL', () async {
    final httpClient = HttpClientSpy();
    final url = faker.internet.httpUrl();
    final sut = RemoteAuthentication(httpClient: httpClient, url: url);

    await sut.auth();

    verify(httpClient.request(url: url));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a instrução when

```
when(httpClient.request(url: url)).thenAnswer((_) async {});
```

Isso serve para retornar um valor quando o método da classe Mock for chamada, caso contrário ele retornaria um null

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Tenta desse jeito:

```
    Future<void>? auth() async {
    await httpClient.request(url: url);
    }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).